# How to get first alphanumeric character after the first occurance of a set of possible symbols using MYSQL REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm having diffficulty with a regular expression.
I have a MYSQL table with ABC notated tunes in it that look a bit like this:

```
X: 1
T: Spórt
M: 6/8
L: 1/8
R: jig
K: Dmaj
|:AdF ~A3 | GBE ~G3 | AdF ~A3 |
GBE cde | AdF ~A3 | GBE ~G3 |
cdc A2G | EAA D3 :|
```

I want to make a search function in MYSQL that will list tunes in order by their starting note. In this case I need to return `A`

Most tunes begin with either : a bar-line `|`, a repeat bar-line `|:`or no bar-line (which means I have to match the first character on the first line that has bar-lines in it)

Any suggestions of what regex would do this? I find regexpressions extremely confusing!

Comment: So row 7 matches the condition?

Comment: Unfortunately not always! ABC tunes can have any number of extra fields on separate rows like composer etc!

Answer (score 0):

Try: `\|:?([A-Ga-g])`

- `\|` matches `|`
- `:?` matches `:` if there is one
- `([A-Ga-g])` Gets a note.